# What is the "co-derived set" in topology?

Tags: general-topology

Definition 2.9 in this [paper](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272990/1-s2.0-S1571066119X00055/1-s2.0-S1571066119300350/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEFkaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIQCSOKfSJHfnmMauY0f5KpLRKHT%2BWTU42dink3DLr6Yi2wIgKdvK7%2F0H%2Bhw%2BXJCDMm10ecFwNBhK7jgC8XUxBJWGdbEq%2BgMIURAEGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDISLwg9l%2BE2jDCLcFirXAyNZxJIl35crrPLb%2BBcfDMHWsJy%2BOd6Ro30JUk8RIdiRvwyoKE00xklBdF%2FdD%2F31kOjH9ga76vz0CmMKZ4BhYyCQbghOwK5XZN3JQNZh8f%2BRiTTBbXhwPiOPNqtPYr085XerRbiR%2FauFbfOvJj1arET51YHNX0IkrMugDszp5gBZwDJqOCOZxjo1Wds5IOQlZC2wDMVUyDUrOXGPB7JUaFQAYM29mZEJykUDB4UD6BZUVfFGjQpFup0pUI2D31ICL3TJYLKciUybZzAnMT9r5rqz3dxGL0MGcSpb7TMTEGkFyIfdc87xFRUouWrAS4f5VG8AOqzawWSVPwgVi3i%2FjKYlLl%2BsSelOYbzz6uXg%2BORmBc1pRwMwVPrtUHowKMONRlfST0jIiz%2Bk9sNcl8OrIFCreq1SYkPnMUaneS4tPGOMRzoNFEO9hTFqxq4AViAGS6TDKo4La%2FNEgrl5xjWnCm7QhRz2AJ5E%2BWzdUS%2FMKTBv2o3eQllTxPZaFi9l2Yv1ABm%2FYr8m9Wa%2BkwIfrIjOtX0jhOSUk108rC2Yjos53ygqFE30jm8QB78gAkvh4WGZbk87kIsM5isRBFNCUI7Ve7ukvOkZ7B4dvGkCbCXZSvpn75dtEiWyzzCAopSOBjqlAYkmVOGXz%2BSZnQnA4zUtzLLe3UCH94IpbGeYgYPz2aZCHmu2K3y2WX3ybst%2F7pdrqgivgsasMY8PJGMrn6sI%2B9VXoYpnrFP0a5WvfG9qOiCr8QqrexTdDB0HHiN61wJP6LFaRFD1Mkst8kMuL1veJ9ynl2kdh6OvARkj3uOoHSqIf5HUdt6XIzmWIdb%2F%2FlIbMt2oaopnO3yFxI7LEFgoLdt%2B%2BHWZwg%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20211224T011119Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTY6WQMTK2V%2F20211224%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=beadc71db2c7715c799c6ae51ed5a92aec8d70df2adf1514d6756e22792af511&hash=f1cb3310a1e226d8c75eec7b022de6e1888164ee74e831b72d7458f72fffbb10&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S1571066119300350&tid=spdf-f807adf4-882f-498a-85bc-1c4d03519cf2&sid=dfd551d12937094e6a28f87930259342ac83gxrqb&type=client) introduces a co-derived set operator $f$ (in the paper the operator is denoted by $\mathbf{Cod}$). The function $f:\mathcal P(X)\longrightarrow\mathcal P(X)$ is characterized by the following properties:

- $f(X) = X$,
- $x\in f(A)$ iff $x\in f(A\cup\{x\})$,
- $A\cap f(A)\subseteq f(A\cap f(A))$, and
- $f(A\cap B) = f(A)\cap f(B)$

for each $A,B\in\mathcal P(X)$.

My question is now: what is the co-derived set operator? More precisely, there is also derived set operator $g$ (Definition 2.6 in the paper; in the paper the derived set operator is denoted by $\mathbf{Der}$, but it is also common to use a prime to denote the derived set). The derived set operator is a function $g:\mathcal P(X)\longrightarrow\mathcal P(X)$ that is characterized by

- $g(\emptyset) = \emptyset$,
- $x\in g(A)$ iff $x\in g(A\setminus\{x\})$,
- $g(A\cup g(A)) \subseteq A\cup g(A)$, and
- $g(A\cup B) = g(A)\cup g(B)$

for each $A,B\in\mathcal P(X)$.

For this operator I already know that it corresponds to the set of all limit points of a set $A$. That is, $g(A)$ is the union of all points $x\in X$ such that for every $U\in\mathcal T$ with $x\in U$ it holds that $A\cap (U\setminus\{x\}) \neq \emptyset$, i. e. , $$g(A) = \big\{x\in X : \text{$A\cap (U\setminus\{x\})\neq\emptyset$ for all $U\in\mathcal T$ with $x\in U$}\big\}.$$
I am looking for a similar description of $f(A)$. Does $f(A)$ describe the set of all interior points of $A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The axioms for $f$ are constructed from those of $g$ (which is the *derived* set operator) by replacing $\cup$ by $\cap$ and vice versa, interchanging $\emptyset$ and $X$ and reversing the inclusions where appropriate. So its axioms are **dual** to those of the derived set and that's why it's named the **co-derived** set operator I think.

They're dual in the same way as closure and interior operators are, if you look at *their* axioms.

I think that if $g$ is a derived set operator, $f(A)=g(A^\complement)^\complement$ will be a co-derived set operator and vice versa. The paper mentions that too, I saw.

Just like a set is closed iff it contains its derived set, we have the dual fact that a set is open iff its a subset of its coderived set. I don't think an alternative description is very enlightening. It's a completely artificial "Spielerei".

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, @henno brandsma. You certainly have a point: the co-derived set seems to describe the dual notion of limit points. So my question could be rephrased as: "what is the dual notion of limit points?". My first thought was the set of interior points because some of the properties (those of which I could find a proof) are also satisfied for the set of interior points. May I ask you whether you have an idea of what the dual of limit points could be? Or is there none, as your last sentence suggests?

Comment: @Syd it's those points that are not limit points (in the usual sense) of the complement of $A$. Translate that into open sets...